# Connection between Azure Data Factory and Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm wondering what is the most appropriate way of accessing databricks from Azure data factory.

Currently I've got databricks as a linked service to which I gain access via a generated token.

Comment: Hardly to answer such question,any issues you met?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Please edit your question with more details and specifics, as currently there is no specific programming question.

Answer (score -2):

What do you want to do?

- Do you want to trigger a Databricks notebook from ADF?
- Do you want to supply Databricks with data? (blob storage or Azure Data Lake store)
- Do you want to retrieve data from Databricks? (blob storage or Azure Data Lake store)

Comment: Please refrain from posting clarifying questions as "answers." These clarifications should be posted as comments under the question (and you have enough rep for commenting). That said: even if the OP chose one of those three choices, it's still too broad.